# How to add a this tag in jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to add a this tag in my jquery so when hoving over my images it shows only one at a time not all of them

Thanks

```
$(function() {
$('.slide').hover(function() {
    $('#show-me-here span').show();
}, function() {
    $('#show-me-here span').hide();
});
});
```

Comment: What tag? This question makes no sense.

Comment: Need to show and hide #show-me-here span from using .slide btn

Comment: It would be very helpful if you provide more input or explanation

Comment: And why doesn't that code work?

Comment: I have multiple #show-me-here is my html so it show all of them

Comment: that breaks conventions. you should only use an id once for one element. Your HTML is effectively invalid. You can use a class multiple times but not an id.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if i understand you correctly, but i assume you want to show something when mouse is over an image, and hide, when its not. if so, use

```
$(function() {
    $('.slide').hover(function() {
        $('.common_class_of_things_you_want_to_hide_on_mouse_over').hide();
        $('.only_things_you_want_to_show_on_mouse_over').show();
    }, function() {
        $('.common_class_of_things_you_want_to_show_on_mouse_out').show();
        $('.only_things_you_want_to_hide_on_mouse_over').hide();
    });
});
```

edit:
since you have multiple show-me's with id's, it wont work, since ID must be unique, use classes instead

Answer (score 1):

So I put your code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DyDNp/) and it works:

### HTML

```
<button class="slide">text</button>

<div id="show-me-here">
<span>
    show me here
    </span>
</div>
```

### JS (no changes)

```
$(function() {
$('.slide').hover(function() {
    $('#show-me-here span').show();
}, function() {
    $('#show-me-here span').hide();
});
});
```

### CSS

```
#show-me-here span
{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing right now is ***overkill!***

This doesn't require javascript at all, use simple CSS.

```
.show-username{
   display: none;
}

.slide:hover .show-username{
   display: block; // or inline, inline-block, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i have managed to do it

```
$(".slide").hover(function () {
    $(this).find(".show-username").show();
}, function () {
    $(this).find(".show-username").hide();
})
```

Comment: I would recommend not answering your own questions like this, instead, edit your original post and add this at the end, and accept someone else's answer. Just a thought